# Angular controller can't get 'this'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have issue to controller when i trying to get 'this' from controller it gives me other object

In html i have created like this

```
<div ng-controller='AppController as ctrl'>
   <input type="text" ng-model='ctrl.firstName'>
</div>
```

In javascript

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', ($scope, $http) => {
   const ctrl = this;
}
```

and when i was trying to get ctrl.firstName it gives me undefined

How can i fix this issue ? what's wrong here ?

Comment: Where's your `firstName` defined?

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model='ctrl.firstName'> here and you can try $scope.save = () => { console.log(ctrl.firstName) }

Comment: `var ctrl = this; ctrl.firstName = 'iniitial value';` works? Inside the controller. You should see it in html.

Comment: can you create a fiddle as your should work ?

Comment: For your code, it can be like this `const ctrl = this; ctrl.firstName = 'initialValue'`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ftwko0jv/1/

Comment: @sky it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is that app is not defined in your controller file. You need to declare is above, e.g.:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Don't forget to pass in all the necessary dependencies into that declaration.